# AngularJs $resource return my Java Enum as an array from a REST service

Tags: java, angularjs

I'm pretty new with AngularJs, and I have some trouble retreiving correctly a Java enum from a Rest service.
With the code I put at the end of this question, here is the result I got :
{"0":"C","1":"U","2":"S","3":"T","4":"O","5":"M","6":"E","7":"R"}
It's an array, but I was excpecting a simple String.
Maybe I just miss how to transform this as a String ? But I can't find a correct way to do that ...

Here is my controller :

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('LabController', function ($scope, LabService) {

    $scope.clientOuAbonneResultat = '';

    $scope.clientOuAbonne = function () {
        LabService.get({noClient: 10002782, noContrat: 1003}, function(result) {
            $scope.clientOuAbonneResultat = result;
        });
    };

});
```

My service :

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('LabService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/lab/clientOuAbonne', {}, {
    });
});
```

My backend implementation :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/lab")
public class LabResource {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LabResource.class);

@Inject
private LabService labService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/clientOuAbonne",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public CustomerTypeEnum getPeriodeFacturation(@RequestParam(value = "noClient") long noClient,
                                              @RequestParam(value = "noContrat") long noContrat)
        throws URISyntaxException {
    return labService.isClientOuAbonne(noClient, noContrat);
}
}
```

And finally, the enum :

```
public enum CustomerTypeEnum {
    CUSTOMER, SUBSCRIBER, NONE;
}
```

Comment: Angular $resource expects an object or an array of objects. Is that the format of your response from return labService.isClientOuAbonne(noClient, noContrat) ?
}

Comment: My method `labService.isClientOuAbonne(noClient, noContrat)` return just one value of the enum CustomerTypeEnum

Comment: you need to convert java enum type to json Format. For example: {CustomerType: 'CUSTOMER'}

Comment: How do I do that ? My annotation `@RequestMapping(value = "/clientOuAbonne",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)` isn't supposed to convert automatically my enum to json format